# How to get all requests from apache serever

Tags: php, apache, http

I have an apache server with php running on my server with several Vhosts. I am going to create an analysis system for server and to do so I need to get all http requests on a page and then process it as usuall. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Did you check for access log?

Comment: Access log has a lot of additional information and processing them will get server time and resources. I just need the requests Hosts and Parameters

Comment: Use some kind of parser (there's a lot, just google it) and use/store whatever you want, else you will need to modify your application and store the data you want

Comment: Perhaps this will get you started: https://github.com/kassner/log-parser